# webpack function usage after bundling

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, bundle

I try to pack that https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jscad/dxf-deserializer library and use in browser.
Uage from node looks like

```
const deSerializer = require('@jscad/dxf-deserializer')
const rawData = fs.readFileSync('PATH/TO/file.dxf')
const jscadCode = deSerializer(rawData)
```

How should i use that now after linking bundle script?

I had tried

```
let objs = deserialize(fileText,'square10x10',{output: 'csg'})
```

and got

```
ReferenceError: deserialize is not defined
```

There is js test file works fine with node

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const test = require('ava')
const { CSG, CAG } = require('@jscad/csg')

const { nearlyEqual } = require( '../../../test/helpers/nearlyEqual' )

const { deserialize } = require( '../index' )

const samples = path.resolve('../../node_modules/@jscad/sample-files')

//
// Test suite for DXF deserialization (import)
//
test('ASCII DXF from Bourke 3D Entities to Object Conversion', t => {
  //const dxfPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../../sample-files/dxf/bourke/3d-entities.dxf')
  const dxfPath = path.resolve(samples, 'dxf/bourke/3d-entities.dxf')
  t.deepEqual(true, fs.existsSync(dxfPath))

  let dxf = fs.readFileSync(dxfPath, 'UTF8')
  let objs = deserialize(dxf,'aaa',{output: 'objects'})

// expect one layer, containing 2 objects (CSG, and Line3D)
  t.true(Array.isArray(objs))
  t.is(objs.length,2)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding

```
node: {
   fs: "empty"
}
```

`fs` module isn't defined in the browser.
Maybe that's what stopping `deserialize` from been created. With a try.

Comment: I tried,but that solution dont give me some effect.Sometime when i build projects with fs i get Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' - node.js.Your solution help to fix it.But in that case project builds fine.